# Forcing ligature between any two letters

Tags: macros, symbols, ligatures

I frequently find myself confronted with naming new operator in my mathematical research. What I would really want is them to *not* consist of two different letters that have a space between them. E.g. `\operatorname{CG}(x)` typesets as the top figure from the sketch below. But what I would really like it to look like is the bottom sketch! Though it is OK, if the ligature is not exactly as I drew it by hand.

Also, it would be great if there were some way to do this automatically, so that I won't need to spend time for each pair of letters coding "by hand" a ligature. I envision something like a function `\ligatureoperatorname{CG}(x)` that produces the bottom sketch for any two letters (bonus: arbitrary number of letters).

I also realize that it might be really hard to do this, in case there is no font or other clever means available, so I'd be happy with partial solutions too.

Thank you very much.

---

[image]

Comment: why use a form that none of your readers can duplicate?

Comment: Creating fonts is a real work of art and ligatures are meant to be legible, reproduced, and above all not disfigurating the text. I can't imagine a way to achieve that on *arbitrary couple of letters*.

Comment: I would also have no idea how to do this automatically, and normally it is also not the best idea to introduce new symbols or notation - people might get confused :) But I would be interested to see if this can be done, just as a proof of concept, so +1.

Comment: I have actually good reasons to ask for this. It relates more to psychology and what is perceived as being a single token.